# Upcasting/Downcasting in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, downcast, upcasting

I am trying to understand upcasting and downcasting in Java and I am confused by the following scenario (about my code, which is below):

First - why is it that the code does not compile when I include the line `myAnimal.bark();`,

and Second - (assuming I comment out `myAnimal.bark();`) why does calling `myAnimal.move()` print `"moveDog"` instead of `"moveAnimal"`? Isn't `myAnimal` restricted to methods from the `Animal` class because we have declared its type to be `Animal`, even though we are setting it to a type of `Dog`?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Here is the code:

```java
    public class Animal {
        public void move() {
            System.out.println("moveAnimal");
        }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          Dog myDog = new Dog();
          Animal myAnimal = myDog;
          myAnimal.move();
          //myAnimal.bark();
       }
    }

    class Dog extends Animal {
        @Override
        public void move() {
           System.out.println("moveDog");
        }

        public void bark() {
            System.out.println("bark");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Animal::bark` method does not exist so can not be called.

Comment: *Isn't myAnimal restricted to methods from the Animal class* - this is what OO is all about.  *An instance method in a subclass with the same signature (name, plus the number and the type of its parameters) and return type as an instance method in the superclass overrides the superclass's method.*

Comment: Yes, then why is it printing moveDog, instead of moveAnimal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the implicit upcast at this line:

```
Animal myAnimal = myDog;
```

You are not doing anything to change the underlying instance `myDog`. What you are doing is assigning it to a variable of a type one level higher in the inheritance tree. Effectively, this restricts which methods can be called to only those defined in `Animal`, but does not change how those methods resolve.

Because you have restricted the methods available to only those defined on the parent class `Animal`, the compiler cannot resolve `Dog#bark()`, since it is a method of `Dog`, and the variable `myAnimal` is defined to be of type `Animal` which has no `#bark` method.

`#move()` is a method of both `Animal` and `Dog`, so it resolves, but it resolves to the method defined on `Dog`, since `myAnimal` still refers to an instance of `Dog`, despite being upcast.

Comment: Nice answer in easy to understand English

Answer (score 4):

There are two important concepts which are competing with each other here.

The first concept is **static typing**, which means the Java compiler checks the types of your expressions, variables and methods **at compile-time**, before the code ever gets a chance to run. In this case, the variable `myAnimal` is of type `Animal`, and the type `Animal` does not have a method `bark()`, so `myAnimal.bark()` is a type error.

The second concept is **dynamic dispatch**, which means that the method implementation is selected based on the type of the object **at runtime**. Since `myAnimal` holds a reference to an object of the class `Dog`, the call to the `move()` method invokes the implementation of that method provided in the `Dog` class.

Answer (score 0):

Here you declared the myAnimal as Animal and every animal can't bark! i.e myAnimal is referring to Animal here.

Animal myAnimal = myDog;

But for sure Dog is an animal which can bark, hence you need to explicitly cast your myAnimal by letting JVM know its of type Dog and not Just Animal.

So if you change //myAnimal.bark(); to below it will work!

((Dog) myAnimal).bark();

Here we casted myAnimal from Animal to Dog. hence bark() method is allowed and it does not give any compilation issue.

Hope this helps!